# What is the effect of the temperature on the no of moles in an equilibrium system?

Tags: equilibrium, mole

Here's something that makes me confuse. What will happen to the total no of moles in a system if the temp is raised. Will it increase? If so how is that possible.?
Say we have an equlibrium,
$$\ce{2P <=> Q + R}$$ 
The temp is $300\:\mathrm{K}$ and total no of moles is 6 moles. 
If we increase the temp upto $500\:\mathrm{K}$ will the total no of moles change to 10 moles when the volume and pressure kept constant?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! Have a look at the [tour] and the [help] to familiarize yourself with our site.

Comment: No, because there are the same number of molecules on either side of that equilibrium.

Comment: Oh thnx. But will it increase if the equation doesn't have the same no of molecules on either sides?

Comment: The quantity ‘amount of substance’ shall not be called ‘number of moles’, just as the quantity ‘mass’ shall not be called ‘number of kilograms’.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your equation contains the same number of moles either side, so temperature does not matter.

But if the equation had different moles on either side, it should be given if the reaction is endothermic or exothermic.

For eg- if a reaction is exothermic and the temperature is increased, then according to Le Chatelier's principle, the reaction should go in the backward direction (To compensate for the increase in temperature).
So, if the reactant side has more moles than product side, the number of moles will be increased. You can apply similar logic if the reaction is endothermic.

Comment: E.G. 2 NO2 <=> N2O4, in which there are twice as many molecules on the left hand side. This reaction is easily reversible near room temperature; see http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/demos/main_pages/21.1.html.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Therefore we can safely conclude that the reaction is exothermic.